# extending the nav bar

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to extend the nav bar all the way across the screen but have the beginning of the menu items stay the same horizontally - but black nav bar extended all the way left and right. currently my nav bar is just in the center

also trying to change font color of menu items in nav bar and add one of those nav bar searches that is just a magnifying glass

Comment: please show code and/or create a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) so we can see what you have tried.

Comment: im new to this, not sure what a fiddle is. but as for code. do you mean post my style sheet?

Comment: I mean your html/css.

Comment: man I dont think you found the key. this question is a mystery. // ya.. post all relevant code. its really not understandable what you are talking about. but its ok

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9hwyzgtf/ - thats my css.

Comment: paste your html in the html section with it please.

Comment: oh derp thought i did. i pasted it and hit run but it is all junbled up on jsfiddle. i just did view source on my page and copy. or was there a specific html file i needed on the website? I have filezilla if i need to track it down.

Comment: ok just paste the html and the css that creates/applies to the navbar you are having issues with.

Comment: well if i knew what that was i would be messing with it. im sure there is some value i need to change. just not sure which.

Comment: Do you have a link to the live site?

Comment: offtopicpolitics.com

Comment: are you wanting the logo all the way to the left also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block of html you are looking for is below:

```
<div class="clearfix container">
    <div class="site-branding">
            <a href="http://www.offtopicpolitics.com/" title="OffTopicPolitics">
                <img src="http://www.offtopicpolitics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/offtoptest.png" alt="OffTopicPolitics">
            </a>                            
           <!-- .site-branding -->
    </div>          
    <nav id="main-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <a href="#main-navigation" class="nav-open">Menu</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-close">Close</a>
        <div class="clearfix sf-menu">
            <ul class="sf-js-enabled">
                <li class="current_page_item">
                    <a href="http://www.offtopicpolitics.com/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-7">
                    <a href="http://www.offtopicpolitics.com/contact/">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- #main-navigation --></nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason it is not 100% width of the screen is because your bootstrap `.container` div only goes up to a width of 980px.

To resolve this you could change `container` to `container-fluid` and then in your css apply 0 padding to the container like so:

```
.container-fluid {
    padding: 0;
}
```

This will make the entire headers width span 100% of the page.

If you would only like the navbars width to span 100% of the page and not the entire header do what I have suggested above but also wrap just your `.site-branding` div in a container like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="site-branding">
        <a href="http://www.offtopicpolitics.com/" title="OffTopicPolitics">
            <img src="http://www.offtopicpolitics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/offtoptest.png" alt="OffTopicPolitics">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you resolve this current issue!

Comment: yea that extended the nav bar- but it brought the logo and menu to the left with it.

Comment: Read the last part of my answer. Did you wrap the .site-branding div in a container?

Comment: no, i guess i was not sure how to do it. i will have to try again when i get home. btw im trying to get it to look similar to how reuters.com has theirs. thanks again man - how do i +rep you or something

Comment: You can give rep by upvoting an answer (clicking the up arrow next to the answer). Also by accepting my answer gives me rep. Thanks man let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: OK, i just im not sure which file i need to edit the container field in. would that be header.php? and then paste that css code in my custom css editor?